# Firebase updateChildValues function blocks other Firebase functions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using updateChildValues function to update values for 500 students in the database, when I trigger it and try to trigger another Firebase function like observe, the second function (observe) not performs and keeps waiting until the first operation (updateChildValues) completes, which takes nearly 15 seconds.

This is my code for updateChildValues:

```
@IBAction func menu(_ sender: Any) {
        let storeRecord = UIAlertAction(title: "Store attendance record", style: .default) { action in
            var attendanceTimesDict = [String: Int]()
            var absenceTimesDict = [String: Int]()
            for student in self.students { // 500 students
                if self.attendanceRecord[student.identifier] == true {
                    student.attendanceCount += 1
                    attendanceTimesDict["\(student.identifier)/attendance"] = student.attendanceCount
                } else {
                    student.absenceCount += 1
                    absenceTimesDict["\(student.identifier)/absence"] = student.absenceCount
                }
            }
            Database.database().reference().child("class").child("CS101").child("records").child("27-4-2019").updateChildValues(self.attendanceRecord)
            Database.database().reference().child("class").child("CS101").child("students").updateChildValues(attendanceTimesDict)
            Database.database().reference().child("class").child("CS101").child("students").updateChildValues(absenceTimesDict)
        }
}
```

And this is my code for observe function:

```
func getStudentsList() {
        Database.database().reference().child("class").child("CS101").child("students").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let studentObject = child.value as? [String: Any]
                if let name = studentObject?["name"] as? String {
                    let student = Student(identifier: child.key, name: name)
                    self.students.append(student)
                }
            }
          self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database server performs one operation at a time, to ensure that it always returns a consistent state.

If you want to prevent a single large write operation from blocking other operations for a long time, you'll split that large operation into multiple pieces.

Comment: I tried setValue instead of updateChildValues, but it freezes the app.

Comment: There is no significant performance difference between calling `setValue` or `updateChildValues` with the same data. To make a difference you will have to split the large operation into multiple API calls.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this please?